# Can I move my kitchen to the front of the house or any other ideas?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

I recently purchased this 3/4 bedroom house. I liked having the additional room space downstairs (converted garage) but do not like how it is separated from the rest of the house.

Also, the kitchen would need to be extended as it is quite small. The current layout is awkward, with you having to walk through the lounge from the kitchen to the existing dining area.!

My initial idea is shown below. This would increase the size of the kitchen whilst have the garage conversion tail off of the living room making it more entwined with the rest of the house (in my opinion).

[image]

How easy do you think it would be to move the kitchen to the lounge or does anyone have any better ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are the current drains/upstairs bathrooms in relation? Is the bay window full height, or just a protruding window? Do you know if the wall you're proposing demolishing hollow, or solid?

Comment: The biggest part of any way you go with this is going to be dealing with the load bearing walls. Do you know which ones are? Is there a basement level below this? What type of foundation? Adding a beam will mean creating new point loads where the beam is supported, and these need to be supported down to the foundation. Remember, the load is the same, but it's going to be supported by two points holding up a beam instead of distributed across the length of the wall. Depending on how things are constructed, you may need to install new footings in the foundation to make this possible.

Comment: While you're at it you might consider opening the wall between the front hall and what is now the lounge. Did that in my place (required some engineering since it _was_ load bearing)  and it made the space much more welcoming. The stairs are now a decorative element for the living room,  light flows thru the place better, and the room feels more open and better proportioned. It also makes moving stuff into or out of the house easier.

Answer (score 3):

There are several factors to consider here.

1) If the inside wall on the right side of the kitchen is a load bearing wall it could not be simply ripped out. It would likely have to be replaced with a beam to properly support the upper level.

2) If this first floor layout is built on a concrete slab then it is likely that some of the utilities are through and under the concrete. For sure the drain would be like this. The point being that moving such utilities is a major rework of the slab.

3) Kitchens normally have multiple electrical circuits routed to them. These would have to be re-routed or additional circuits added to the new location.

4) The existing bump out window implies some extra exterior wall construction details that may include foundation and 2nd level interface details that may impact the exterior in a fairly major way if removed.

So those are just the first things that come to mind.

In the end I would say that the project is possible if money, time and patience are available in plentiful quantities. But you also need to weigh if the investment balances with the value of the property, how long you intend to stay in the property and how/where you would live whilst a major project like this is undertaken.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Michael Karas' answer.

Instead of rearranging the rooms, I think it would be better to leave the kitchen where it is. To do what you are proposing is a major task, and in my opinion is not necessary.

It typically is not a good design to have the front entry open directly to the kitchen. There are very few homes that have that kind of layout. Your current layout is actually pretty close to ideal.

I think the best bang for your buck would be to open up the wall in between the kitchen and the dining area. As Michael already noted, this might be a bearing wall. It is not possible to tell whether that wall is a bearing wall, or a partition wall just by looking at the blue print.

I would recommend that you hire an engineer to look at the wall and see if it is a bearing wall. If it is, then you would have to modify the framing and most likely install a beam to carry the weight.

This will do two things. The first is that it will open up your kitchen area to the dining area so you don't have to go down the hall and through your lounge area to go from the kitchen to the dining area. That is pretty inconvenient, especially if you have guests. It will also give you the opportunity to expand the size of your kitchen.

This also has the advantage of letting you leave the plumbing fixtures in place. To make the changes you are proposing would dramatically increase the cost of this renovation. If you just opened up the kitchen wall, the cost of this renovation would be much more affordable.

I would also recommend partially closing off the wall in between the dining area and the lounge. A set of french doors, or something similar would work well there. This would make the dining area a little bit more formal. It would also allow you to expand the size of the kitchen.